# What's wrong with this linked list function?

Tags: c++, linked-list

The context is the one of a `L` linked list. I'm assuming that L is not 0 at the beginning and that every linked list end with a node that has NULL as next field.

```
void g(node*, int, char);
void g(node* L, int k, char y) {
    node* current = L;
    if (current->info == y) k--;
    while (current->next) {
        if (current->next->info == y) {
            if (k > 0) k--;
            else {
                node* very_next = current->next->next;
                delete current->next;
                current->next = very_next;
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

I keep getting a BAD_ACCESS warning at the level of `while(current->next)`. What's wrong? I'm accessing a correct node over there, because the test `(!current->next)` failed. So what's wrong?

The linked list I'm testing is

```
node* n = new node('a',new node('b', new node('a', new node('c', new node('a', 0)))));
```

with this struct:

```
struct node {
    char info;
    node* next;
    node(char a = 0, nodo* b = 0) {
        info = a;
        next = b;
    }
};
```

Comment: I see some `node`s and some `nodo`s? Can you just copy your actual code?

Comment: @BrendanLong, fixed. "nodo" is "node" in italian. I just translated it for better understanding.

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/TzzkiniO My guess is that there's something in the code you're not showing us (like your main() function).

Comment: @BrendanLong, if you try with 1 instead of 10 is gives segmentation fault: http://codepad.org/e8afyUmV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `current->next->next == very_next = NULL`, wouldn't current get assigned `NULL` as well, thus making the later access to current (via `current->next`) invalid (`current = current->next = very_next`)?

Comment: This is actually the real problem. He is right. If current->next becomes NULL, then at the end of the while current = current->next which can be 0.

Comment: I think also, if you set current = current->next after a delete, you skip a node in that iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption inside the loop that current->next->next is pointing to a next element can be wrong, you should check first if this is true.

Comment: If current->next is != 0 then current->next have surely an info field. Also if current->next is != 0 it surely has current->next->next (which may also be 0).

Comment: Sorry I was trying to reply to piokuc. I agree that this isn't the problem.

Comment: @BrendanLong, also in the context of this exercise, every node had either a correct node->next or an empty (0 / NULL) node->next field which is still correct but just empty (it doesn't contain neither next nor info).

Comment: @BrendanLong, sorry for the misunderstanding.